# What are my options for creating a hierarchy of pages in SharePoint Online?

Tags: navigation, modern-experience, modern-pages, pages, sitepages

If I have Page A, Page B, Page C, Page D and Page E, I’d like to structure them in the following hierarchy:

- Page A

  - Page B

    - Page C
  - Page D
- Page E

With a publishing portal, I’d have simply put the pages into folders. However, I’m not sure on the “best” way to do this with the modern experience.